# How do I remove jcrop?

Tags: jquery, jcrop

how do i un-jcrop an image?

I'm adding jcrop with a;

```
$('#imgThumbnailer').Jcrop({
    onChange: statusCrop,
    onSelect: statusCrop,
    bgColor: 'black',
    bgOpacity: .3
});
```

How do I go about undoing it?

Edit:

```
$('#imgThumbnailer').attr("src", $obj.attr('thumbnailer_link'));

var dlg = $("#ThumbnailDialog").dialog({
    modal: false,
    draggable: false,
    position: 'center',
    zIndex: 99999,  // Above the overlay
    closeText: '',
    width: 510,
    height: 500,
    open: function () {
        $('body').css("overflow", "hidden");
        if ($.browser.msie) {
            $('html').css("overflow", "hidden");
        }
        $("#loader").show();

        var ratio = parseFloat($obj.attr('thumbnailer_ratio'));
        jcrop_api = $.Jcrop('#imgThumbnailer', {
            onChange: statusCrop,
            onSelect: statusCrop,
            bgColor: 'black',
            bgOpacity: .3,
            aspectRatio: ratio
        });

    },
    close: function () { $('body').css("overflow", "auto"); if ($.browser.msie) { $('html').css("overflow", "auto"); } $("#loader").hide(); },
    buttons: {
        'Set Thumbnail': function () {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        },
        Cancel: function () {
            jcrop_api.destroy();
            jcrop_api = null;
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    }
}).parent();
dlg.appendTo(jQuery('form:first'));
```

The above code will not work for me. I think this has to do wth the fact that Im using this within a jquery dialog. http://code.google.com/p/jcrop/issues/detail?id=21

Not sure exactly how to go about fixing it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Edit: Looks like you need to maintain a reference to the api when you add jcrop to an image.

```
// assign jcrop to jcrop_api
var jcrop_api = $.Jcrop('#imgThumbnailer', {
    onChange: statusCrop,
    onSelect: statusCrop,
    bgColor: 'black',
    bgOpacity: .3
});


// when you want to remove it
jcrop_api.destroy();
```

Comment: When i initialize jcrop that way, it doesn't initialize :-/

Comment: is too short: I've put the code above. I believe its a bug in jcrop.
@Jeff the Bear: No error. all the JCrop divs are set to 0px height and width with display: none.

Comment: This works. i had to upgrade jcrop to the latest developer version

Answer (score 79):

I was wondering the same thing and after reading the source have found a simple solution that works in v0.9.8 (the other posted answers only work with the dev version currently). If you initiate Jcrop like this:

```
$('#imgThumbnailer').Jcrop({
    onChange: statusCrop,
    onSelect: statusCrop,
    bgColor: 'black',
    bgOpacity: .3
});
```

then you can get access to the api and destroy Jcrop via:

```
JcropAPI = $('#imgThumbnailer').data('Jcrop');
JcropAPI.destroy();
```

It's probably too late for the asker but hopefully this is helpful to someone who stumbles upon this page from google!

Comment: Indeed, this was heaps useful for me. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: This stopped me from pulling my hair out. Thank you for that bit.

Comment: In particular, there seems to be some interaction with jQuery UI Dialog which means this way is the way to go even now the release version is up to `0.9.10`.

Comment: Exactly what I've wasted a whole day looking for! Thank you so much, @foob!

Comment: Remember folks this can be shortened to $('#imgThumbnailer').data('Jcrop').destroy()

Answer (score 4):

As of version v0.9.9 of Jcrop, you need to do it the following way:

```
var jcrop_api;
$('#target').Jcrop(options,function(){
    jcrop_api = this;
});
```

Courtesy of the creator: http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop_API.html