# How to reset the Jcrop plugin? I.e. How to allow changing the source of the target image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jcrop

The application I'm working on allows users to add an unlimited number of images onto a viewport. With those images, a series of operations are allowed: *resize*, *drag*, *rotate*, and *crop*. For the cropping feature, I'm using the *Jcrop* plugin.

When clicking on the control icon for cropping, a lightbox appears, that shows the selected image (the `<img>` element is one and the same, only the `src` attribute value changes each time) and allows the user to crop it. The event handler associated triggered when the *crop* icon is clicked is:

```
$(document).on("click", "div.cropper", function(){

            var ctrl = $(this),
                ref = ctrl.attr("reference"),
                obj = returnObj(objects,ref),
                target = $("#crop-target")
                crop_params = {};

            target.attr("src",obj.src);
            target.Jcrop({
                onSelect: function(c){
                    crop_params = c;
                }
            });
});
```

Given the code above, the cropping works perfectly, but ONLY with the first image I try it on. When I click on the "cropper" icon for any other images after that, the first image is shown.

How can I work around this problem?

PS: I've searched through the already existing questions about Jcrop and couldn't find an answer to my particular problem.

Comment: may I know what is returnObj do and what is reference?

Comment: You need to reset your co-ordinates on onClick event. Or just remove jCrop and initialize again. see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466333/how-do-i-remove-jcrop

Comment: @Sandy It seems that I've completely missed the post you gave me the link to when searching. And **foob**'s answer was the perfect solution to my problem. Thank you very, very much, Sandy!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create a new img tag and start jCrop with that.

```
$('#parent_tag #img_to_crop').remove();
$('#parent_tag').html('<img id="img_to_crop"></img>');
$('#parent_tag #img_to_crop').Jcrop({ options ... });
```